# Patch :update / post :update aborted when testing AMS

Tags: active-model-serializers

As I was trying to test out Active Model Serializers, I encountered an issue when attempting to do a **patch :update** or **post :update** on **ActionController::TestCase**. This is the abort output:

```
deovandski@deovandski-VirtualBox:~/Fakktion$ rake test
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/deovandski/Fakktion/test/controllers/api/v1/genres_controller_test.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>
/home/deovandski/Fakktion/test/controllers/api/v1/genres_controller_test.rb:54: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end
/home/deovandski/Fakktion/test/controllers/api/v1/genres_controller_test.rb:58: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:244:in `rescue in load_dependency'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/home/deovandski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Below is the **Genres Controller Test** with only the test case in question. Setup, Teardown and all other tests can be found through this [link](https://github.com/Deovandski/Fakktion/blob/master/test/controllers/api/v1/genres_controller_test.rb).

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::V1::GenresControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "API - Update a genre" do
    genre = Genre.find_by name: 'test'
    genre.name = "mikuchan"
    patch :update, id: genre.id, ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(genre).as_json
    genreUpdated = Genre.find_by name: 'mikuchan'
    assert_response :success, genreUpdated
  end
end
```

The root seems to be `patch :update` line from above as the abort states an unexpected **/n** when it was expecting an **=>**. However, when I removed `id: genre.id`, the following error showed up instead:

```
Api::V1::GenresControllerTest#test_API_-_Update_a_genre:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"api/v1/genres", :data=>{:id=>"980190963", :type=>"genres", :attributes=>{:name=>"mikuchan", :eligibility_counter=>"0", :posts_count=>"0"}, :relationships=>{:posts=>{:data=>[]}}}}
    test/controllers/api/v1/genres_controller_test.rb:46:in `block in <class:GenresControllerTest>'
```

The above output looks like a correct payload, so the problem seems syntax related. However, the only other way that I found was using **genre.save** which is not what I am looking for since this procedure only uses ActiveRecord...

With that, what is correct approach for testing post :update on AMS? Also, does the procedure change if I am using **:json_api** as the adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a matter of syntax as the appropriated syntax is:

```
tempResource = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(resource).serializable_hash

post :update, tempResource.merge(id: resource)
```

This is an example testing for CREATE, SHOW, PATCH and DELETE for a resource:

```
require 'test_helper'

class Api::V1::GenresControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  # Called before every test
  setup do
    @request.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    @testGenre = Genre.new(name: 'TEST', eligibility_counter: 0, posts_count: 0)
    @testGenre.save
  end
  # Called after test
  def teardown
    @testGenre = nil
    @apiGenre = nil
    @genreSerialized = nil
  end
  test "Genres - API - Get Index" do
    get :index
    assert_response_schema('genres/index.json')
  end
  test "Genres - API - Serializer Validation" do
    sampleSenre = Genre.new
    serializer = ActiveModel::Serializer.serializer_for(sampleSenre)
    assert_equal GenreSerializer, serializer
  end
  test "Genres - API - Create 200" do
    apiGenre = Genre.new(name: 'luka', eligibility_counter: 0, posts_count: 0)
    assert_difference('Genre.count', +1) do
      post :create, ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(apiGenre).as_json
    end
  end
  test "Genres - API - Create 422" do
      post :create, ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(@testGenre).as_json
      assert_response(422)
  end
  test "Genres - API - SHOW 200" do
    get :show, id: @testGenre
    assert_response_schema('genres/show.json')
  end
  test "Genres - API - UPDATE 200" do
    genre = Genre.find_by name: 'test'
    genre.name = "mikuchan"
    tempGenre = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(genre).serializable_hash
    post :update, tempGenre.merge(id: genre)
    genreUpdated = Genre.find_by name: 'mikuchan'
    assert_response :success, genreUpdated
  end
  test "Genres - API - UPDATE 422" do
    genre = Genre.find_by name: 'test'
    genre1 = Genre.find_by name: 'movie'
    genre.name = "mikuchan"
    genre1.name = "mikuchan"
    tempGenre = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(genre).serializable_hash
    tempGenre1 = ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(genre1).serializable_hash
    post :update, tempGenre.merge(id: genre)
    post :update, tempGenre1.merge(id: genre1)
    assert_response(422)
  end
  test "Genres - API - DELETE 200" do
    assert_difference('Genre.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @testGenre
    end
  end
  test "Genres - API - DELETE 422" do
    genre = Genre.find_by name: 'song'
    post = Post.first
    post.genre = genre
    post.save
    delete :destroy, id: genre
    assert_response(422)
  end
end
```